# "This server does not support FTP over TLS" warning in vsftp. Why does it appear?

Tags: debian, ftp, ssl, tls, vsftpd

I've got a small VM set up, which runs Debian.

In my `vsftpd.conf` file, there are the following lines:

```
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
connect_from_port_20=NO
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=ftp
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=45000
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_deny=NO
ssl_enable=NO
```

When I connect with my machine to test my FTP settings (through FileZilla), this warning appears:

```
Insecure FTP connection

    This server does not support FTP over TLS. If you continue, your password and files will be sent
 in clear over the internet.

Host: the IP address of the VM
Port: 21
```

But, to my knowledge, `ssl_enable=NO`in the `vsftpd.conf` file means "Don't use SSL/TLS", which I don't want to, since it's an introductory project to FTP for me. This warning doesn't appear when I connect to the VM using my machine's terminal.

What's the issue? Is it a FileZilla thing to always ask for SSL/TLS, regardless of what the server settings are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning appears because your server doesn't support TLS. It's shown by FileZilla.

> But, to my knowledge, `ssl_enable=NO` in the `vsftpd.conf` file means "Don't use SSL/TLS",

Yes, exactly. Setting this to `NO` isn't supposed to remove the warning – indeed it is why the warning *is being shown in the first place.* The specific purpose of this message in FileZilla is to make the user agree to the lack of TLS.

Note that the warning doesn't say anything like "the server claims to support TLS but we failed to enable it", which might be the case if there was a technical issue with your server's configuration (e.g. if you had ssl_enable=YES but no certificate).

Instead the warning simply says "the server does not support TLS", so it's not a certificate error or anything, but the absence of TLS *in itself* that FileZilla considers to be a problem – in the same spirit as web browsers warning about filling in forms over plain HTTP.

Comment: I see, it's an FYI for the user, not a warning in regards to the server. Thank you

Comment: Yes, although at the same time it's _kind of_ a warning in regards to the server – in the sense that the lack of TLS has been slowly moving towards being considered "misconfiguration" for quite a while now.  The message doesn't *explicitly* say so, but it's why the message exists at all.  (Web browsers also have been adding "warn if no HTTPS" features recently.) So these days installing a TLS cert should already be part of your introductory FTP project.

Comment: Yeah, I know it should be, but I'm first getting started on the absolute basics to get something working, not have something work as if it were an actual FTP server. That's why I shied away from SSL/TLS. But I appreciate the input greatly!